# Regex en Postgres para seleccionar todo tras la última coincidencia

Tags: postgresql, regex

Uso PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
y necesito seleccionar, de un campo `VARCHAR` llamado `cadena`, todos los dígitos `[0-9]` que haya tras la última letra `[A-Z]` en una cadena de caracteres. Mi mejor intento ha sido

```
substring (cadena, '[A-Z]([\s\S]*)$')
```

En la cadena **2L19099**, esta expresión me devuelve lo que busco: **19099**. Pero, de la cadena **RG6861**, devuelve **G6861**, cuando lo que necesito es que me devuelva **6861**. Aclaro que no todas las cadenas tienen el mismo número de letras ni estas están en la misma posición.
¿De qué forma podría conseguirlo?

Comment: Esa consulta da error. ¿Seguro que es la que estás usando? Qué versión de PGSQL usas?

Comment: Para poder responder tu pregunta, lo primero que debes dejar claro es ¿cuál es el criterio de selección? ¿Es cuando aparece algo que no sea una letra que buscas seleccionar? Prueba algo como `[A-Z]+(?=[^A-Z])([\s\S]*)$`. Acá te dejo el [playground](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3XwEdjuS3edJ9NaWsQ2EZ4/0).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Ese código funciona como necesito. ¿Podrías, por favor, exponerlo en respuestas y explicarlo para entender cómo funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues dile que revise 0 a N carácteres, luego 1 a N letras y luego retorne 0 o más números

```
select substring('RG6861' , '^[0-9A-Z]*[A-Z]+([0-9]*)') as pepito
```